# Multiply nested dicitonary values by values inside the same nested dictionary

Tags: python

Can i multiply values inside nested dictionary?

This is my dictionary:

```
row1 = {'XAxis': {'X1': 0.2, 'X2': 0, 'X3': 0.75}, 'YAxis': {'1A': 0.1, '2B': 0.2, '3C': 0.45}
```

And i want to multiply the XAxis values with the YAxis in order to get this:

```
row1 = {'XAxis': {'X1': 0,02, 'X2': 0, 'X3': 0,34}
```

How is that possible?

### EDIT:

Or instead of multiply in can also be a sum of the two values.

This 1st answer is good but not the ideal solution since it isn't scalable, cause sometimes im gona have more than two Axis, so i dont want to hardcode the "XAxis" and "YAxis".

Comment: Why that particular result? Do you want `X1 * 1A`, `X2*2B`, and `X3*3C`?

Comment: @chepner Yes, the answer there is the multiplication you've done there

Comment: Then what do you want if there are multiple axis, if you can't hardcode `XAxis` and `YAxis` in the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dict comprehension:

```py
row1 = {'XAxis': {'X1': 0.2, 'X2': 0, 'X3': 0.75}, 'YAxis': {'1A': 0.1, '2B': 0.2, '3C': 0.45}}

output = {'Xaxis': {k: v1 * v2 for (k, v1), v2 in zip(row1['XAxis'].items(), row1['YAxis'].values())}}
print(output) # {'Xaxis': {'X1': 0.020000000000000004, 'X2': 0.0, 'X3': 0.3375}}
```

Note that this assumes that you are using fairly recent python version (3.7+) so that dicts preserve order.

If you need to round the numbers, use `round(v1 * v2, 2)` instead.

---

The following works for more general situations, although it becomes quite complicated:

```py
from operator import methodcaller
from math import prod
row1 = {'XAxis': {'X1': 0.2, 'X2': 0, 'X3': 0.75}, 'YAxis': {'1A': 0.1, '2B': 0.2, '3C': 0.45}, 'ZAxis': {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}}

keys = next(iter(row1.values())) # get the keys from the first (inside) dict
output = {k: round(prod(v), 2) for k, *v in zip(keys, *map(methodcaller('values'), row1.values()))}
print(output) # {'X1': 0.02, 'X2': 0.0, 'X3': 0.34}
```

Comment: This is good, the only "problem", is that i want this to be scalable, cause sometimes im gona have more than two Axis, so i dont want to hardcode the "XAxis" and "YAxis", but for now your resolution works

Comment: @ObamaVEVO I've added an attempt to address that.

Comment: @ObamaVEVO you should accept this answer since it is the answer.